# how to add custom icons in navbar of a jQuery mobile page

Tags: jquery-mobile, navbar

In jQuery mobile page, how can I add custom icons in navigation bar? My footer content is given below:

```
<footer data-role="footer">  
     <div data-role="navbar" >  
         <ul>  
              <li><a href="#" data-icon="abc"> Abc </a></li>  
              <li><a href="#" data-icon="xyz"> xyz </a></li>  
          </ul>  
      </div>  
</footer>
```

CSS file contains

```
.ui-icon-abc
{
    background-image: url('common-images/c.png');
    background-size: 60px 60px;
}
```

However this doesn't work. it shows a circle but not the image. I tried with other SO ( [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138213/issues-while-creating-custom-icon-for-navbar-in-jquery-mobile) and [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9582451/jquery-mobile-navbar-icons-not-appearing)). However, that didn't help me.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to improve your css a bit, this will work (Your icon icon also needs to be smaller for this **.ui-icon-** method to work):

```
.ui-icon-abc
{
    background: url('common-images/c.png') no-repeat rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) !important;
    background-size: 16px 16px;
}
```

Take a look at my example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/Q9TrF/

Comment: Thanks for your help. How can I add a large icon?

Comment: If you are not in hurry I will make you another example in few hours.

Comment: I am not in hurry. If you can do that, I will be grateful. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Or if you are in hurry take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/6307302/1848600 ,  good working example